# Spinner is not working in Fragment

Tags: android, spinner

My application crashes when I am using Spinner in Fragment.

```java
public class TestRideFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] country = { "India", "USA", "China", "Japan", "Other",  };

    public TestRideFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_ride, container, false);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_ride, container, false);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spin.setAdapter(aa);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
 }
```

Could anyone help me spot the issues with my code, please?

Comment: Where is your logcat ?

Comment: i think you need  to delete extra comma after "Other" in your country array.

Comment: Post your xml code

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get view before it's being created, so that's why it is returning null.

So, you can do like,

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

or, you can move your code to onViewCreated where view will be created,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_ride, container, false);



}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1)` also make sure that spinner1 is declared in the xml layout fragment_test_ride

Try adding array in strings.xml

```
<array name="countries">
    <item>India</item>
    <item>USA</item>
    <item>China</item>
    <item>Japan</item>
    <item>Other</item>
</array>
```

and in your xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/countries" 
   android:id="@+id/spinner1" />
```

Remove the ArrayAdapter but do not this one will make your options static based on whats in the array declare on the string xml

Comment: Below is the XML CODE ---

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1">

        </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>

Comment: XML for spinner

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Into this:

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Comment: I changed the as guided by you, Its working fine Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your adapter which should be;

```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    country, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

and you have;

```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
```